# XSLT - Group similar nodes together and remove duplicate nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I've the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<R>
  <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>1</B>
  </M>
  <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>2</B>
  </M>
  <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>3</B>
  </M>
  <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>4</B>
  </M>
</R>
```

Here if we assume 'M' is the main node, 'H' is header and 'B' is the body, I want to have only one 'M' node with single 'H' and all 'B' nodes under it.

Basically I want to move all the 'B' nodes to first 'M' node and remove all other 'M' and 'H' tags.

Can any one help me on achieving this.

Expected output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<R>
  <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>1</B>
    <B>2</B>
    <B>3</B>
    <B>4</B>
  </M>
</R>
```

Here is my current XSLT Script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <R>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|M/*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|M/B" />
        </R>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is currently shown as version 1.0, but are you able to use XSLT 2.0? For grouping issues such as this, it is much more straight-forward to use XSLT 2.0 and above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple description "Basically I want to move all the 'B' nodes to first 'M' node and remove all other 'M' and 'H' tags" seems to be easily solved by

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="R">
      <xsl:copy>
          <M>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="M[1]/H | M/B"/>
          </M>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG

Not sure whether there is any grouping needed if you have various values for the `H` elements.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, it looks promising, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, your solution worked for me, but I've another problem with attributes. I've a namespace attribute that I need only for the route node, but I'm getting an empty attribute for all the child nodes. I demonstrated the problem here https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/12

Comment: If you want elements from the input to be transformed to a different namespace then you need to set up a template doing that e.g. `<xsl:template match="H | B"><xsl:element name="{local-name()}">...` should suffice given the default namespace you have on the stylesheet's root element: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/13

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin. Accepted your answer.

Comment: while I am doing so, I noticed that attributes are missing in the result XML. Here I've an attribute ccy="GBP", which is missing in the result XML. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/28

Comment: Try to figure it out on your own, if you can't then post a new separate question with the necessary details of minimal but complete samples of XML input, wanted output, code you have and the wrong result you get.